# Issues with page.JumpToData()

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, datatable

I am using [this](https://datatables.net/) and have a datatable in my page.

I am receiving values from another site pages, and according to them I should redraw table.

I am receiving BookNo value, and when table is loaded, I should open page where this BookNo is placed. (If it is placed on page 2 or 3, I should open those page).

I found [this](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData()) and tried to use it:

```
var dtApi = new $.fn.dataTable.Api("#Book_grid");
dtApi.page.jumpToData(selectedBookNo, 1);
```

but, this has falled with `TypeError: dtApi.page.jumpToData is not a function`. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Added:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register('page.jumpToData()', function (data, column) {
       var pos = this.column(column, { order: 'current' }).data().indexOf(data);

       if (pos >= 0) {
           var page = Math.floor(pos / this.page.info().length);
           this.page(page).draw(false);
       }

       return this;
    });
```

This was missed. Now I don't have any exceptions, but this does't do a thing at all.
When script goes to setting `var pos`, I am receiving -1 no matter what, which means, I simply cant receive data? How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the code example on the page you linked to, your code should be:

```
var dtApi = $("#Book_grid").DataTable();
dtApi.page.jumpToData(selectedBookNo, 1);
```

Comment: Same exception. I should add your example probably, because it was the first thing I tried. Tried to use $.fn.dataTable  because .DataTable() didn't worked out.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the jQuery selector right? I would check that there is an element on the page with id 'Book_grid'. Also, try using the Developer Tools in your browser to see what `dtiApi` is.

Comment: Im sure, because I have plenty of other things that work with  `var dtApi = new $.fn.dataTable.Api("#Book_grid");` The thing I am not sure is `jQuery.fn.dataTable.Api.register( 'page.jumpToData()',` - As I understand it is neccesary, but there it is and where to place it if it doesn't exist...